# Change variable in script with chrome console

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, variables, selenium-chromedriver

The website have the button like this

[image]

When I click it will call the script below:

[image]

```
function count(){
let downloadTimer;
var timeleft = 30;
downloadTimer = setInterval(countDown,1000)
function countDown(){
  document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML = "Wait " ;
  document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft ;
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft < 0){
  clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "1414-YYYI"
  }
}

$(window).blur(function(){
  console.log("blurred")
  clearInterval(downloadTimer);
})
$(window).focus(function(){
  console.log("focuesed")
  downloadTimer = setInterval(countDown,1000);
})}
```

How I can change timeleft variables when I run function count() with google console
[image]
I can run function count but I can't change timeleft variables

Comment: Put code in your question, not images of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access that variable, but you can redefine the function.

```js
function count() {
  var timeleft = 30;
  console.log("time left: " + timeleft)
}

count();

var entire = count.toString();
var body = entire.slice(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));
var count = new Function((body).replace("30", "2"))

count();
```